# Why doesn't this string.Format() return string, but dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
@{
    ViewBag.Username = "Charlie Brown";
    string title1 = string.Format("Welcome {0}", ViewBag.Username);
    var title2 = string.Format("Welcome {0}", ViewBag.Username);
}
```

In the MVC view I use the values like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(title1, "Index")
@Html.ActionLink(title2, "Index")
```

Here, the `title1` works fine. But the `title2` ActionLink failed with a compiler error:

> CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'StandardHeader' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

`string.Format()` has quite a few overloads, but the return type is always **string**. Why does the variable declaration using `var` fail here?

Comment: I doubt that you got that error message from the code you've given. I suspect it's a different bit of code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, so we already know from comments and other answers that the problem is in `dynamic`. Since `dynamic` is bound *on runtime*, only at that time is the overload resolution and type validating is done.

So: if at least one of the parameters is `dynamic`, the overload resolution is done at runtime.

That is why this obvious mistake is allowed:

```
dynamic x = "";
int i = string.Format("{0}", x);
```

It doesn't bother if there isn't a `string.Format` overload that returns an `int`. It evaluates that later on.

Comment: *All* expressions are evaluated at runtime, with the occasional exception of some operations on compile time literals.  This is not specific to `dynamic`.  What's deferred here is overload resolution and the the type of the expression is determined at runtime.  That's different.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. Thanks @Servy

Comment: Cool. That explains why. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy There is no overload resolution with `int i = x;` but it still compiles. Any thoughts on that? (From your comment I understood it shouldn't work, or did I read wrong?)

Comment: @PatrickHofman `dynamic` is implicitly convertible to any type.

Comment: @Patrick, Servy means the _"the entire expression is treated as it was dynamic and evaluated on runtime"_ part. The overload resolution (and thus the return type lookup) is done at runtime, where the assignment will fail.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have got that clear, I have updated the answer. Thanks @CodeCaster

Comment: The edit hasn't changed the fact that the answer is just wrong.  The expression isn't going to be evaluated until runtime *even if `dynamic` isn't involved*.  All that's actually being affected is the type validating and overload resolution.  How the expression is evaluated is entirely unchanged.

Answer (score 11):

The error message is telling you *exactly* what's wrong here:

> Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

`title2` is of type `dynamic`.  You need to cast it to `string`, since you know that's what it is.

Comment: But `string.Format()` doesn't return `dynamic`.

Comment: @David - It will be `dynamic` if `ViewBag.Username` is dynamic. `dynamic` applies to the entire expression.

Comment: @CodeCaster *Every* method can return `dynamic` if any of its arguments is `dynamic`.

Comment: It would be worth explaining *why* the type of `title2` is `dynamic` here. The explanation Lee gave is the crucial bit of this question, IMO.

Comment: @Servy: Nit pick: if the *argument* is dynamic. Making the *parameter* type `dynamic` has no effect.

Comment: @Servy, can you clarify a bit more on why it is still a `dynamic` please? It is indeed confusing.

Comment: @Blaise The variable is dynamic because you assign a `dynamic` expression to it.

Comment: @Servy, and the return type of the `string.Format()` method does not count?

Comment: @Blaise No, the return type of the method is irrelevant to the static type of the expression when `dynamic` is involved.  That's the whole point of dynamic typing, to explicitly ignore the type at compile time.

Comment: Interesting, learn something new every day.  @Blaise: Put the first code block in the controller method and take a look at the Locals in the debugger.  `title2` is indeed of type `dynamic {string}`.  I mean, it *is* a string, but the type system had to make sense of the whole expression as best it could with a `dynamic` in the mix there.

Answer (score 7):

It's the view bag which is dynamic.
[image]

If you use actual username (instead of ViewBag.UserName)it would work.
Or cast `(string)ViewBag.Username` into string.